# Realm Android queries return wrong result

Tags: android, database, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I have table which has a structure as follows:

```
public class GroupDailyDB extends RealmObject{
    @PrimaryKey
    private int groupId;
    private String groupName;
    private String groupDescription;
    private int groupStatus;
    private boolean hasImage;
    private int sweatPoints;
    private long steps;
    private int rank;
    private float percentile;
    private int noOfUsers;
    private boolean isCurrentUserPartOfGroup;
    private boolean isCurrentUserOwner;
}
```

My data is getting saved successfully 
[image]
My json when refreshes does not send group Id 3 and I need to change its status.

The code for checking is as follows:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < groupModel.getData().size() ; i++){
    GroupDailyDB groupDailyDB = 
           realm.where(GroupDailyDB.class)
           .notEqualTo("groupId",groupModel.getData().get(i).getGroupId())
           .findFirst();
    Log.i(TAG,"Group id delete daily:  "+groupDailyDB.getGroupId());
}
```

But my log prints id 4,5 respectively it never returns me id 3

Comment: What thread is this on?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce realmAsyncTask

Comment: Print this before loop and see the value returning ? groupModel.getData().size()

Comment: So the value returns 2 and I print id from json its 4,5 which is right

Comment: Since you don't sort the result, the `findFirst()` will return the first element it finds, no guarantee the one with smallest `id` will be returned. You may want to use `findAllSorted(xxx).first()` instead.

Comment: @beeender Well I tried this
GroupWeeklyDB groupWeeklyDB = realm.where(GroupWeeklyDB.class)
                            .notEqualTo("groupId", groupModel.getData().get(i).getGroupId())
                            .findAllSorted("groupId").first();

I get same id thrown once which are avaliable

Answer (score 1):

So, think about this... You have a list of 3 objects, each with  a unique ID value. You loop over some other list of ID values, querying the 3 objects where its ID is not equal to the current ID of the loop.

That query is going to return 2 elements for the case of a matching ID (you filtered it out) and 3 elements for a non-matching ID. You only get the first element of these queries, and you are confused about missing data?

In the case of the unique ID values, you should use `equalTo` to find the one element that matches. Also might want to add some exception check for when no ID value is equal (when findFirst returns no object)

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't your code be something like

```
RealmQuery<GroupDailyDb> query = realm.where(GroupDailyDB.class);
for(int i = 0 ; i < groupModel.getData().size() ; i++){
    query = query.notEqualTo("groupId",groupModel.getData().get(i).getGroupId());
}
GroupDailyDB groupDailyDB = query.findFirst();
Log.i(TAG,"Group id delete daily:  "+groupDailyDB.getGroupId());
```

?

Comment: Even tried doing this but doesnt works gives me all id